# Show sum of any element is equal to zero in a ring

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given $x$ is in $\mathbb Z_n$, show the sum with $n$ terms $x+x+...+x = 0$
, by using the ring axioms.

My approach so far:

$~~~~x+x+...+x$

$=1\cdot x+1\cdot x +...+1\cdot x~$  (Uniqueness of 1)

$= (1+...+1)\cdot x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$     (Distributivity)

$=  0\cdot x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ **i doubt this if i can directly take $1+...+1=n=0~(mod~n)$**

$= 0$

I doubt why I can take $1+...+1=0$ but not using $x+x+...+x=n\cdot x =0$ directly

Comment: This proof seems perfectly fine

Comment: i doubt why i can take $1+...+1=0$ but not using $x+x+...+x=n\cdot x =0$ directly

Comment: Well 1 can not be a zero divisor because if $m \ne 0$ then $m*1  = m$.  And if $n*1 = m \ne 0$ then $(n-m)*1 = m - m = 0$ and as $n-m \in \mathbb Z_p$, 1 is impossibly a zero divisor.  So $n*1 = 0$ and $m*1\ne 0$ for $0<m < n$.  We can't directly make that argument with $x \ne 1$ because $(n-m)*x = 0$ need not be a contradiction.

Comment: @fleablood therefore is my approach wrong? thanks

Comment: No!  Therefore your approach is perfect!  You *can* conclude 1+1+1....+1 = 0.  And doing so *is* justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concerned whether we can assume $1+1+.... + 1 = n*1 = 0$.  And if we can assume it, the why can't we simply assume $x+x + ... + x = n*x = 0$?

Lemma:  $n*1 = 0$.

Pf:  if not, then $n*1 = m\ne 0; m \in \mathbb Z_n$.  So $0 < m < n$.  So $(n-m)*1 = n*1 + m*1 = n-m = 0$.  But $0 < n-m < n$ so $n-m \in \mathbb Z_n$ so $m = n \equiv 0 \mod n$.

i.e.  $n*1 = 0$.

And with this now proven, your proof is just fine.

Comment: Cool ! I appreciate u so much by the clear and understandable explanation !

Comment: It is interesting that I took it so much  for granted the n*1 = 0 that I *did* have to think and go back to definitions to figure this out.